# running darwine from commandline?

Tags: wine, darwine

i have some proprietary command line tool for windows and i wonder, if it's anyhow possible to "turn it into" a command line tool for osx. what i would like to know -- is it possible to run a windows cli-only tool on osx using darwine? from osx terminal?

thanks!

Comment: Anyway, I suggest you use Wine Bottler rather than Darwine - see http://winebottler.kronenberg.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from http://wiki.winehq.org/MacOSX/FAQs:

```
cd "/Users/Me/where/is/my/app/" && exec /path/to/executable/wine "myapp.exe"
```

Save this as a shell script, for example. I don't have Darwine right now, but I think it should work

Comment: thanks ... this was already very helpful. i'll just have to play around some more withit -- do you know, how to avoid starting X11? afaik i should not need it for a cli application? i googled around and found something about using "ttydrv" in .wine/config, but this doesn't seem to work ...

Comment: I found this on the page of Wine Bottler
http://winebottler.kronenberg.org/trac/wiki/WineCmdLine

again, I don't use darwine much

Comment: yes, i'm using this -- but it opens x11. anyway ... thanks for your answer it helped me a lot!